# Laravel & phpunit set expected http error code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, tdd

I'm writing some tests. Here is my test:

```
  /** @test */
  public function a_normal_user_cannot_access_the_admin_panel()
  {
    // Note: This is a regular user, not an admin
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $this->actingAs($user);
    $this->visit('/admin');

    // ????
  }
```

In my `MustBeAdministrator.php` middleware:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      $user = $request->user();

      if ($user && $user->isAdmin) {
        return $next($request);
      }

      abort(403);
  }
```

When i visit `/admin`, the middleware aborts with a 403 error. How can i assert with phpunit that an http error was thrown?  I know about `$this->setExpectedException()`, but i can't get it to work with http error.  Am i doing this wrong?

NOTE: I'm very new to phpunit and also exceptions, so sorry if this is a stupid question.  Here is the [repo for this project](https://github.com/SelectiveAlso/mbcdb) if you need any other files, or you can just ask.

Comment: Hey, you can post an answer to your own question, it's not prohibited :)

Comment: @iScrE4m I did answer it, but SO won't let me accept it as an answer for 2 days :( I'll accept it then.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice, SO didn't show me in a review :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$this->actingAs($user);
$this->setExpectedException('Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException');
$this->get('/admin');
throw $this->response->exception;
```

[Found this article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/testing-that-exception-was-thrown).  Adding the `setExpectedException` line, the `throw` line, and changing `visit` to `get` seemed to solve my problem

Comment: @MihkelAllorg SO won't let me accept it for another 2 hours. I will then.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the full response object, you may use the `call` method

```
/** @test */
public function a_normal_user_cannot_access_the_admin_panel()
{
  // Note: This is a regular user, not an admin
  $user = factory(User::class)->create();
  $this->actingAs($user);
  $response = $this->call('GET', '/admin');

  $this->assert(403, $response->status());
}
```